# API platform and Symfony, multiple entity managers and dynamic connection problem on some api operations

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, api-platform.com

The following code shows a solution that almost everything works fine. But not everything ...
I am trying to use separate mysql databases for clients.

This is how the databases structure should look:

> SystemEntityManager:

- database_system

> AccountEntityManager:

- database_account_1
- database_account_2
- database_account_3
- database_account_4
  ...and more and more...

When logged user (with proper JWT token) request API Platform I use a mechanism that selects the appropriate database.
It works during the create, delete and get collection operations.

But... this does **NOT** work during the get item or update operation
The cause of this problem is wrong database selection.
During these operations an attempt is made to download data from the database_system instead of database_account_1 etc

Problem appear when I request from swagger documentation and functional tests.

This is my doctrine.yaml with configuration for two entity manager:

- system
- account (this is dynamic connection with multiple client databases)

```yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: system
        connections:
            system:
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
            account:
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
                wrapper_class: App\Doctrine\DynamicConnection
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: system
        entity_managers:
            system:
                connection: system
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
                mappings:
                    System:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/System'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\System'
                        alias: System
            account:
                connection: account
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
                mappings:
                    Account:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Account'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Account'
                        alias: Account`
```

Class to switch connection:

```php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Doctrine;

use Doctrine\Common\EventManager;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Driver;

final class DynamicConnection extends Connection
{
    public function __construct(
        array $params,
        Driver $driver,
        ?Configuration $config = null,
        ?EventManager $eventManager = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($params, $driver, $config, $eventManager);
    }

    public function switchConnection(int $account): void
    {
        if ($this->isConnected()) {
            $this->close();
        }

        $params = $this->getParams();
        $params['dbname'] = AccountDatabaseHelper::getAccountDatabaseName($account); // return account_1 or account_2
        parent::__construct($params, $this->_driver, $this->_config, $this->_eventManager);
    }
}
```

When request come from API and User is logged then I switch database (I am use user->id as prefix of database )

```php
namespace App\Doctrine;


use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ControllerEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;

class AccountContextControllerEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private AccountContextService $accountContextService;
    private TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(AccountContextService $accountContextService, TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->accountContextService = $accountContextService;
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    public function onKernelController(ControllerEvent $event)
    {
        if (!$event->isMainRequest()) {
            return;
        }

        if ($this->tokenStorage->getToken()) {
            $this->accountContextService->switchAccount($this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser()->getId());
        }
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::CONTROLLER => "onKernelController"
        ];
    }
}
```

This is my service with EventDispatcherInterface (this service is used above code)

```php
namespace App\Doctrine;

use Psr\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface;

class AccountContextService
{
    private EventDispatcherInterface $dispatcher;

    public function __construct(EventDispatcherInterface $dispatcher)
    {
        $this->dispatcher = $dispatcher;
    }

    public function switchAccount(int $account)
    {
        $this->dispatcher->dispatch(new AccountContextChangeEvent($account));
    }
}
```

And event subscriber:

```php
namespace App\Doctrine;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class DoctrineAccountContextService implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $accountEntityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $accountEntityManager;
    }

    public function onAccountContextChange(AccountContextChangeEvent $event): void
    {
        $this->switchAccount($event->getAccount());
    }

    public function switchAccount(int $account): void
    {
        $connection = $this->entityManager->getConnection();

        if ($connection instanceof DynamicConnection) {
            $connection->switchConnection($account);
        } else {
            throw new \LogicException("To switch connection to selected account, connection object must be instance of " . DynamicConnection::class);
        }
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            AccountContextChangeEvent::class => "onAccountContextChange"
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: By default, the system entity manager will be injected for EntityManagerInterface unless you changed it somewhere.  So DoctrineAccountContextService::__construct will receive the wrong manager.  I can't say that this is the problem.  Your code is interesting but I have not tried switching the way you have it.  I suspect that your 'working' code might actually be switching the system entity manager.  In any event, you might consider creating decorated classes for each of your entity managers and then type hinting against them instead of the interface.  May or may not work.

Comment: Additionally I noticed that my event is on list Not Called Listeners in profiler tool
App\Doctrine\AccountContextChangeEvent
but only on item operations, on collection works fine

Comment: My knowledge of the internals of the api platform is shallow at best.  I'd really expect a controller listener to always be fired unless something prevents the request from getting to the point of selecting a controller.  I assume you have verified that your controller itself is being reached on your item operations?